# ActiveMQ package for R

Tags: r, activemq-classic, message-queue

I'm trying to have a model I've built in R sent messages to an activeMQ queue.  A quick googling of R points me to [`Rjms`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rjms/index.html); however, when I check for the package on CRAN, I get an error saying "Package ‘Rjms’ was removed from the CRAN repository."  Further googling just pushes me back to `Rjms`.

Given this, is there an ActiveMQ package available in the R language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up installing the packages via wget tarballs rather than via github, as I was encountering a Java exception when loading the packages installed via github.

from the command line:

```
wget http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/Rjmsjars/Rjmsjars_0.0.1.tar.gz
wget http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/Rjms/Rjms_0.0.5.tar.gz
```

then within the R interactive terminal:

```
install.packages('~/Rjmsjars_0.0.1.tar.gz', repos = NULL, type ="source")
install.packages('~/Rjms_0.0.5.tar.gz', repos = NULL, type ="source")
```

When loading the package, I am indeed able to initialize a logger and send a message without a Java exception:

```
library(Rjms)
logger <- initialize.logger('tcp://xxx.xx:61616', 'Q', "test")
send.status<-to.logger(logger, "{xxx: xxx, xxx: .xx}")
send.status
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

You can install the current version from Github. First, you need to install the dependency `Rjmsjars`.

```
library(devtools)
install_github("cran/Rjmsjars")
install_github("smschauhan/Rjms/src/main/resources/Rjms")
```

Comment: Thanks.  Why isn't the package on CRAN?

Comment: @Bryan I suppose the package is not actively maintained.

Comment: Thanks.  I was able to install it, but am now encountering an error.  I'll write another ticket for the error and link to this ticket.

Comment: Here's the ticket with the error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27296088/rjms-activemq-exception-when-initializing-logger