# Rjms & ActiveMQ: exception when initializing logger

Tags: r, activemq-classic, message-queue

I installed `R`'s `Rjms` package as I want to send messages to an ActiveMQ message queue already set up (called `test`) for me.  As `Rjms` is not on CRAN, I installed it from github using the directions in [ActiveMQ package for R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27282915/activemq-package-for-r).

However, I noted two things.  When installing `Rjmsjars`, I received a warning saying `No man pages found in package  ‘Rjmsjars’`.  I think this is likely unrelated, but I wanted to include this just in case.

```
library(devtools)
install_github("cran/Rjmsjars")
install_github("smschauhan/Rjms/src/main/resources/Rjms")
```

After I load `Rjms`, I tried to initialize a logger with the following code:

```
library(Rjmsjars)
library(Rjms)
logger <- initialize.logger('tcp://app1.xxx.xxxxx.net:61616','Q','test')
```

However, when I try to do this, I get the following error:

```
Error in .jnew("org/math/r/activemq/logger/Producer", url, type, name) : 
      java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
```

Since the error message isn't very clear, I'm not sure how to fix.  Any thoughts on what's going on?

Comment: also, are there any public ActiveMQ loggers out there, so I can set up a reproducible example for you all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up installing the packages via wget tarballs rather than via github, and did not encounter the same error.

from the command line:

```
wget http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/Rjmsjars/Rjmsjars_0.0.1.tar.gz
wget http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/Rjms/Rjms_0.0.5.tar.gz
```

then within the R interactive terminal:

```
install.packages('~/Rjmsjars_0.0.1.tar.gz', repos = NULL, type ="source")
install.packages('~/Rjms_0.0.5.tar.gz', repos = NULL, type ="source")
```

When loading the package, I am able to initialize a logger and send a message without a Java exception:

```
library(Rjms)
logger <- initialize.logger('tcp://xxx.xx:61616', 'Q', "test")
send.status<-to.logger(logger, "{xxx: xxx, xxx: .xx}")
send.status
[1] TRUE
```